# I want to search organization and users in liferay's global search

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to search organization and users in liferay's global search.
How to achieve this?

I am using liferay OrganizationIndexercust extending BaseIndexer .
But am not able to search organization, when am searching either by guest or by logging in.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use

> OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.search()

to search Organizations and

Use

> UserLocalServiceUtil.search()

to search the Users.

Please check the java doc before calling the search methods, as there are different `search()` methods to search from index or from database.